# How can I call a function which needs string calldata as input parameter?

Tags: calldata, type-casting

I have a function which has an input parameter as string calldata. I don't know how to pass a string to this function. The simple solution gives me a compile error as it cannot convert a string_literal to type string calldata. I don't want to change the signature of the function f if it is possible. Please help me if you have any idea.

```
constructor(uint160 _magic) {
    f("abcde");
}

function f(string calldata s) public allow {
    emit FF(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Functions that accept calldata must be called externally. Calldata is read-only and generated through a blockchain call.
- A contract can call itself externally by calling as `this.f("abdce");`
- While your contract is being constructed, you can not make an external call to one of your functions. Because, `this` contract is unknown till it's written to blockchain and an address is generated for the contract.
- I can recommend implement another functions which calls `this.f("abdce");` and call that function once after the contract is deployed. Don't forget to make it `onlyOwner` or you can implement it as to run only once.

Comment: thanks, but is there any way to run this code without publishing on network? i fwe can change the function signature. i just need to see what the out put is? im not Ethe expert

Comment: You can deploy it to Remix VM and then test it as you want.

Comment: thanks a lot. i tried that, there is another part. sorry to bother you. do you have any idea aout this equation, what could be the X, how to find it?  keccak256(abi.encodePacked((uint160(msg.sender) >> 144))) == X

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve but keccak256(abi.encodePacked((uint160(msg.sender) >> 144))) this code generates a bytes32 value based on the sender address. The same sender always gives the same result. But, X will be different for every sender.

Answer (score 1):

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Test {
    constructor(uint160 _magic) {
        this.f("abcde");
    }

    function f(string calldata s) external {
    // emit FF(s);
    }
}
```

This works. You need `external` visibility and call f using `this.f("abcde")`. I commented out the `emit` event and removed the `allow` modifier and have tested on Remix.

Comment: But, afaik external functions can't be called while it's being constructed.
This should work if the call is made by another function, not from a constructor.